# iteracion de arrays con ciclo for of

Tags: javascript, html, bucles

hola como les va? bueno mi problema es que la funcion boton deberia guardar informacion a travez del array y a medida que se vaya agregando nuevos valores irlos mostrando uno a uno al listado.
esto se que puedo hacerlo con un ciclo for, pero entiendo que tambien se puede con for of.
ahora bien, el array solo muestra un valor, si quiero agregar dos valores me reemplaza el anterior, intento darle vueltas pero no se que esta sucediendo

```js
function boton(){
let cajita = [];

let txtTarea = document.getElementById('txtTarea');
let tareas = txtTarea.value;
cajita.push(tareas);


let listado = document.getElementById ('listado')
 let txt= ' '
 for (let allTareas of cajita){
 listado.innerHTML = txt+=allTareas+ '<br>'
 
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <label> Tareas: </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTarea" name="tarea" placeholder="ingrese su tarea"/>
    <button id="btnAgregar" onclick="boton()"" type="submit">Agregar</button>
    </form>
    <div id="listado"></div>

    
    <script src="listado.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea te causa un problema:

```
listado.innerHTML = txt+=allTareas+ '<br>'
```

`=` es asignación, `+=` también es asignación. La asignación se usa solo 1 vez por enunciado.

Puedes hacer

```
listado.innerHTML += allTareas +'<br>'
```

Comment: gracias en serio por tu ayuda, era eso mismo que me estas diciendo, no tenia claro el concepto de asignación, gracias

Answer (score -2):

```js
function boton(){
let cajita = [];

let txtTarea = document.getElementById('txtTarea');
let tareas = txtTarea.value;
cajita.push(tareas);


let listado = document.getElementById ('listado')
 let txt= ' '
 for (let allTareas of cajita){
// Aca tenes un problema debes inyectar el html fuera del for, primero llena el txt. 
 txt+=allTareas + '<br>'
}
 listado.innerHTML = txt
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <label> Tareas: </label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTarea" name="tarea" placeholder="ingrese su tarea"/>
    // Aca tenes doble comillas al final, quitemos una
    <button id="btnAgregar" onclick="boton()" type="submit">Agregar</button>
    </form>
    <div id="listado"></div>

    
    <script src="listado.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una respuesta que es puro código no es muy útil. Falta una explicación de como esto responde a la pregunta.